# Usefulness of constructing a probability measure on an algebra in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

In [chapter 7 of *Probability Essentials* (Jacod, Protter), p. 40](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~lachout/Vyuka/O-Sem/JacodProtter2004.pdf), distribution functions F are defined as $F(x) = P((-\infty,x])$ and then three characterizing properties are given for a distribution function on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$:

1. $F$ is non-decreasing;
2. $F$ is right-continuous;
3. $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x) = 1$

Then the authors go on to prove that any distribution function has those three properties ($\Rightarrow$) and, vice versa, any function satisfying those properties is a distribution function ($\Leftarrow$).

The proof for ($\Leftarrow$) is quite technical. A set function is defined as $$P(A) \equiv \sum_{1\le i \le n} \{F(y_i) - F(x_i)\}$$
for any A in the set $\mathcal{B}_0$ of finite disjoint unions of intervals of the form $(x,y]$, with $ -\infty \le x \lt y \le +\infty $, which is an algebra. If we can prove that $P$ is a probability, we will have proven that F is a distribution function.

The most complicated part is proving countable additivity for $P$ within the algebra $\mathcal{B}_0$, as one can see in book.

**My question is**, would it not be easier if we defined $P$ on the set $\mathcal{B}_1$ of *countable* disjoint unions of intervals of the form $(x,y]$, with $ -\infty \le x \lt y \le +\infty $ ? In this way, any countable union of sets $A_i \in \mathcal{B}_1$ is in $\mathcal{B}_1$ and defining $P$ as $$P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) $$
trivially yields countable additivity within $\mathcal{B}_1$. Why are we not allowed to do that? What do we lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would make everything harder. For example, if $[a,b)$ is the union of finitely many disjoint intervals $[a_j,b_j)$ it's easy to show that $P$ is finitely additive by showing that $F(b)-F(a)=\sum(F(b_j)-F(a_j))$; proving even finite additivity is much harder iif we alllow infinitely many intervals.

Comment: Why is that? Doesn't $F(b)-F(a)=\sum(F(b_j)-F(a_j))$ hold even if $(a,b]$ (or $[a,b)$) is the union of countably infinite disjoint intervals? Can't we show that the terms cancel out leaving only $F(b)-F(a)$ ?

Comment: The reason it's complicated is that, in contrast  to the case of finitely many intervals, the countably many intervals don't need to be ordered in  a sequence from left to right. For a _simple_ example, $[0,2)$ is the union of the intervals $[0,1/2)$, $[1/2,3/4)$, $[3/4,7/8)$,...$[1,2)$. Now $1$ is one of the $a_j$ but $1$ is not one of the $b_j$, so things don't jut cancel so simply.

Comment: We could avoid that by forcing $a_{j+1} \gt b_j$ on the sets in $\mathcal{B}_1$ but then we would run into the problem again when considering countable unions of the $A_i$, which we need to do if we are to prove countable additivity. So we wouldn't make things easier.Is the issue you pointed out at the heart of the problem and the reason behind the complex proof in the book?

Comment: Well I don't know that book, but yes, this issue is exactly why the proof of this thing is so much more complicated than it seems  it should be.

Comment: Thank you David. Can you recommend me any further reading to learn more about this?

Comment: I dunno - sounds like you have a decent book, reading _it_ thoroughly should keep you busy for  a while. An excellent book on real anlysis would be Folland _Real Analysis_.